# To create a calculated column based on its previous value in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a very difficult problem to solve and I've been at it for days. Our data warehouse is Redshift. This is easy for python and such, but building it in SQL is driving me nuts.

Sample database with week number, total replenishment (additional stock coming in), and estimated unit sold (the ideal forecasted units sold when having enough inventory) :

```sql
SELECT 'W1' AS weeknum, 0 AS replenish, 20 AS est_units_sold
UNION ALL (SELECT 'W2' AS weeknum, 0 AS replenish, 20 AS est_units_sold)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'W3' AS weeknum, 0 AS replenish, 20 AS est_units_sold)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'W4' AS weeknum, 50 AS replenish, 20 AS est_units_sold)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'W5' AS weeknum, 0 AS replenish, 20 AS est_units_sold)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'W6' AS weeknum, 0 AS replenish, 30 AS est_units_sold)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'W7' AS weeknum, 0 AS replenish, 30 AS est_units_sold)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'W8' AS weeknum, 30 AS replenish, 20 AS est_units_sold)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'W9' AS weeknum, 0 AS replenish, 20 AS est_units_sold);
```

The data looks like this

```
W1  0   20
W2  0   20
W3  0   20
W4  50  20
W5  0   20
W6  0   30
W7  0   30
W8  30  20
W9  0   20
```

What I need to create is a column for the beginning inventory of each week, giving W1 beginning inventory (basically today's inventory), for example, 30 units.

**Sodo code:**

```
Week(n) inventory = Week(n-1) inventory - MIN(Week(n-1) inventory, Week(n-1) est_units_sold) + Week(n) replenish
```

The `MIN(Week(n-1) inventory, Week(n-1) est_units_sold)` part is about the actual units sold taking into account inventory, like if we have only 10 in the inventory and the ideal forecasted units sold is 20, we would only sell 10.
What I am stuck on is when creating the `inventory` col, the formula has to refer to itself in the previous row. I couldn't get around this blocker.

Desired result:
[image]

Comment: uhmm, I guess there must be a better way to make a sample dataset right? Please advise!

Comment: Why is inventory 30 for W1?

Comment: @forpas That is given. So it's today inventory, which is what we have.

Comment: The column replenish in the image of your expected results contains different values than the sample data.

Comment: Your desired results are inconsistent, please check each line and include the calculation for each line.

Comment: This can't be solved as a purely set based expression (due to the logic to prevent selling unavailable stock). It can only be solved linearly; processing each week in turn, essentially a loop. That can be done using recursive queries, but it's messy and the antithesis of what SQL is intended for. So, why does this need to be done in SQL?

Comment: Thank you very much for the replies, and I am sorry about the desired result image. I've fixed this. This transformation is part of our data visualization platform (Looker), and it has to be in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid going recursive which can be slow for large datasets you need to unroll the logic.  Here's a solution that uses window functions to perform the query.

Set up:

```
create table test as (
  SELECT 'W1' AS weeknum, 0 AS replenish, 20 AS est_units_sold, 30 as inventory
UNION ALL (SELECT 'W2' AS weeknum, 0 AS replenish, 20 AS est_units_sold, null as inventory)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'W3' AS weeknum, 0 AS replenish, 20 AS est_units_sold, null as inventory)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'W4' AS weeknum, 50 AS replenish, 20 AS est_units_sold, null as inventory)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'W5' AS weeknum, 0 AS replenish, 20 AS est_units_sold, null as inventory)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'W6' AS weeknum, 0 AS replenish, 30 AS est_units_sold, null as inventory)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'W7' AS weeknum, 0 AS replenish, 30 AS est_units_sold, null as inventory)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'W8' AS weeknum, 30 AS replenish, 20 AS est_units_sold, null as inventory)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'W9' AS weeknum, 0 AS replenish, 20 AS est_units_sold, null as inventory)
);
```

The query would look like (left the intermediate calculations in the result so you can see the logic):

```
select *,
    30 + tot_replen - tot_sold - 
        min(overage) over(order by weeknum rows unbounded preceding) as inventory
from ( select weeknum, replenish, est_units_sold,
    coalesce(sum(est_units_sold) over (order by weeknum rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0) as tot_sold,
    sum(replenish) over(order by weeknum rows unbounded preceding) as tot_replen,
    least(coalesce( inventory, 
             sum(coalesce(inventory,0)) over (order by weeknum rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) - 
             sum(est_units_sold) over (order by weeknum rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) + 
             sum(replenish) over(order by weeknum rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
            ), 0) as overage
from test) as sub
;
```

Comment: This is so smart! I love it! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With the simplification of an integer `weeknum` (it can be solved with a string value like `'W?'` also), you can do it with a recursive cte:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT *, 30 AS inv FROM data WHERE weeknum = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT d.*,
         c.inv - LEAST(c.inv, c.est_units_sold) + d.replenish
  FROM data d INNER JOIN cte c
  ON c.weeknum = d.weeknum - 1
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3ffe381be863c454996f7514782e251d).

For your sample data:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT *, 30 AS inv FROM data WHERE weeknum = 'W1'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT d.*,
         c.inv - LEAST(c.inv, c.est_units_sold) + d.replenish
  FROM data d INNER JOIN cte c
  ON SUBSTRING(c.weeknum, 2)::int = SUBSTRING(d.weeknum, 2)::int - 1
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9872a32b821adb2f4f038de4b5476b23).

Comment: The thought of running that on redshift makes me wince. It is, however, the right approach in SQL. (Although, as redshift is for very large data sets, the max recursion limit is potentially an issue.)

Comment: Thank you very much! This works. Recursive CTE is definitely a land I've discovered